# Rsyslog doesn't process log queue from disk

Tags: centos6, rsyslog

We're running rsyslogd on CentOS 6.

We have log forwarding to a central server but the connection was broken due to missing certificates. Now we have processing working again but we have almost 1G of fwdLog1.00000xxx files.

Even after restarting rsyslog multiple times these queue files are not processed. Any ideas on how to force processing of these queue files?

Thanks

These are our settings.

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_FileFormat
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode 
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.domain.com
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueFileName fwdLog1  # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1  # infinite retries if host is down
```